# What does the "Standard Distance" output from the spatial point pattern analysis in QGIS 2 represent?

Tags: qgis, spatial-statistics, saga, qgis-processing

I have a cluster of points and I am using the Spatial point pattern analysis tool from the processing toolbox in QGIS 2. I am having trouble understanding what the "Standard Distance" output is?

It looks to me like it represents two standard deviations from the mean as it covers about 84% of my data, but this is only a guess. I clicked on the help tab of the tool but there were no details there.

Any one know exactly what the "Standard Distance" layer (dotted circle) is showing?

[image]

Thanks

Ando

Answer (score 3):

I assume you are referring to the SAGA tool. SAGA documentation can be [hard to come by](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/saga-gis/wiki/geostatistics_points).

So I went to the [SAGA SVN and found the following code](http://sourceforge.net/p/saga-gis/code-0/HEAD/tree/trunk/saga-gis/src/modules_geostatistics/geostatistics/geostatistics_points/GSPoints_Pattern_Analysis.cpp):

```
StdDist = 0.0;

for(iPoint=0; iPoint<pPoints->Get_Count() && Set_Progress(iPoint, pPoints->Get_Count()); iPoint++)
{
    TSG_Point   p   = pPoints->Get_Shape(iPoint)->Get_Point(0);

    D.Add_Value(SG_Get_Distance(X.Get_Mean(), Y.Get_Mean(), p.x, p.y));

    StdDist += SG_Get_Square(p.x - X.Get_Mean()) + SG_Get_Square(p.y - Y.Get_Mean());
}

StdDist = sqrt(StdDist / D.Get_Count());
```

Code interpretation from @whuber's comment:

> The code computes the root mean squared distance to the centroid. When the points have an isotropic Gaussian ("Normal") distribution and there is more than a handful of them, their distances follow a chi distribution. Therefore, expect about 63% of them to lie within the standard distance of their centroid. 95% of them should lie within 1.73 standard distances of the centroid. This is a *very crude* reference: after all, many point datasets exhibit strikingly non-Gaussian characteristics.

Comment: It would help to have a clearer--preferably quantitative--description of the standard distance.  What is its formula?  (There are several conventions and they vary.)  Roughly what fraction of the dataset is it expected to cover?

Comment: So all this layer is showing is a value/radius demonstrating how concentrated or dispersed the data is? Is this value the average distance of a site from the distributions mean? I'm not sure I get how to make sense of that value! I was hoping to get something showing me that 95% of the population is within this radius - maybe I am using the wrong tool.

Comment: @whuber I dug up the code. I think it is the formula SS_Rebelious posted but with the square root containing 1/n as well.

Comment: +1. The code computes the root mean squared distance to the centroid.  When the points have an isotropic Gaussian ("Normal") distribution and there is more than a handful of them, their distances follow a chi distribution.  Therefore, expect about 63% of them to lie within the standard distance of their centroid.  95% of them should lie within 1.73 standard distances of the centroid.  This is a *very crude* reference: after all, many point datasets exhibit strikingly non-Gaussian characteristics.

Comment: @whuber Hope you don't mind that I added your code interpretation to the answer.